# C# Connect to AD and search over 636 SSL

Tags: c#, ssl, active-directory

I'm very new to C sharp. What I'm trying to do can very easily be done in powershell but I thought of doing this in C sharp. I have a part of a project I'm doing where I have to somehow query Active Directory and get all users. I have two attributes I have to fetch:
1. objectGUID
2. msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed

Then I have to insert this information into a simple SQL table with two columns. I haven't actually got to the SQL table part. Right now, I was purely working on a C# console based application which fetches the accounts from domain.

However, my firm has instructed me to only connect on port 636 to AD. While I was testing this, fetching this data from AD is easy to do on 389. I have the code attached that I've been working on. But I can't figure out why it doesn't work when I add the following line:

```
de.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer;
```

When I include the above line, I get an error on the below line which says:

```
SearchResultCollection src = ds.FindAll();
```

The error is:

> {"An operations error occurred.\r\n"}

Here is the code I'm using. I also don't want to hardcode user/password in this code. This is because it will be called by a scheduler server as a job. The Job will run under a certain security context which will have read access to the AD domain.

```
/////// start of code ///////////////
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace DirectorySearcherTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string adsPath = "LDAP://OU=DisabledAccts,OU=Secondary Accounts,OU=Access Management,DC=dev,DC=net";

            // Create a list of attributes that you want to query from AD.
            List<string> attributes = new List<string>();
            attributes.Add("objectGUID");
            attributes.Add("msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed");
            //----------------------------------------------------------------

            DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(adsPath);
            de.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer;
            DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);
            ds.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User))";

            foreach (string attribute in attributes)
            {
                ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add(attribute);
            }


            SearchResultCollection src = ds.FindAll();

            foreach (SearchResult sr in src)
            {
                ResultPropertyCollection fields = sr.Properties;

                foreach (string ldapfield in fields.PropertyNames)
                {
                    foreach (Object myCollections in fields[ldapfield])
                    {
                        switch (ldapfield.ToLower())
                        {

                            case "objectguid":
                                byte[] myguid = (byte[])myCollections;
                                Guid guid = new Guid(myguid);
                                Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", ldapfield, guid.ToString());
                                break;

                            case "msds-userpasswordexpirytimecomputed":
                                Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", ldapfield, myCollections.ToString());
                                break;

                            default:
                                Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", ldapfield, myCollections.ToString());
                                break;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }


            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}

/////// End of code ///////////////
```